# pygsheets set_dataframe: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, pandas, pygsheets

I am trying to use pygsheets to put a dataframe into a google sheet. However, i am getting a list index out of range error, and can not find any solution.

My dataframe:

```
                   year     month has product?  Sold
year   month                                       
2017.0 November  2017.0  November           x  23.0
       December  2017.0  December           x  34.0
2018.0 January   2018.0   January           x  28.0
       February  2018.0  February           x  22.0
       March     2018.0     March           v  24.0
       April     2018.0     April           v  32.0
       May       2018.0       May           v  27.0
       June      2018.0      June           v  20.0
       July      2018.0      July           v  15.0
```

I am constructing this dataframe by concatenating 3 other dataframes as follows:

```
df3 = pd.concat([year, month,hasProduct,sales],axis=1).reindex(year.index)
```

I then use this dataframe in the following function:

```
def updateSheet():

  df=dictToPandas()

  gc = pygsheets.authorize(service_file='secret.json')
  sh = gc.open("Reports")
  wks = sh.worksheet_by_title("test_sheet") 
  wks.set_dataframe(df,'A2')
```

This produces the following Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):



File "C:\Users\Laila\Desktop\8.py", line 163, in <module>
    updateSheet()
  File "C:\Users\Laila\Desktop\8.py", line 146, in updateSheet
    wks.set_dataframe(df,'A2')
  File "C:\Users\Laila\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pygsheets\worksheet.py", line 979, in set_dataframe
    heads[i].append(col_item)
IndexError: list index out of range
[Finished in 19.4s]
```

I can not find where the error comes from, help is appreciated.

Comment: what is your pygsheets version?

Comment: I have pygsheets 1.1.4

Comment: try using the master version, this issue is fixed in the trunk i think  `pip install https://github.com/nithinmurali/pygsheets/archive/master.zip`

Comment: that worked (had to uninstall the pygsheets i had and then reinstall your version)